# Problem with Rig. Part of one finger does not move with the mesh

Tags: rigging

I tried Recalculating the outside normals, Merge vertices by distance and weight paint but the middle finger does move correctly with the mesh. The top of the middle finger part of the mesh is the problem. The bottom part of the middle finger mesh seems fine. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have included a pic and my .blend file. Thanks in advance!

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/72a204c539cf42a6ad9ffc39ba8680b4 <---- .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in *Edit* mode we can see that you have a hidden bone, and if we check its *Deform* option we can see that it is activated, while I guess it should not because you probably don't want it to weigh on the fingers, so deactivate this option and it should work fine. Also, disable the *Deform* option for all the bones that are not supposed to weigh on the mesh, and maybe even reparent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!